# SwiftUI bug - Text view is changing line spacing when selected

Tags: swiftui

I have a `Text` view that is changing line spacing upon selection:

| Before Selection | After Selection |
| --- | --- |
| [image: before selection] | [image] |

Here's the code powering the view:

```
struct MessagesView: View {
    @Binding var messages: [Message]
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
            List(messages, id: \.id) { message in
                HStack {
                    if message.role == .user {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Text(message.content)
                        .textSelection(.enabled)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .padding()
                        .background(message.role == .user ? Color.blue : Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                    if message.role != .user {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .id(message.id)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Messages")
            .onChange(of: messages) { messages in
                guard let lastMessageID = messages.last?.id else { return }
                withAnimation {
                    scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(lastMessageID, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
            if isLoading {
                LoadingBubble()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? Intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed that problem with a trick way. I add a big lineSpacing of Text like `.lineSpacing(10)`. and that was fixed.